# Java - how to split whole words in JTextArea

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem with JTextArea.

Screen:

[image]

JTextArea makes whole words splitted. Is it possible to change it?

Comment: Whole words splitted? Where? Do you want to force the text to be together without spaces? Please specify your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This has been answered several times already. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: for example in 3rd line we have "browsin" and in the next line is lonely "g".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you should do:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

I took this information from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: -1, this suggestion was given earlier. No need for a duplicate answer.

Comment: @camickr, other suggestion was given several seconds before mine. I have not removed mine because it contains additional information.

Comment: It was given 3 minutes before you answered. If you thought it was a good idea then you can up vote and then add a comment if you think it needs additional information. This is how one good single answer is created.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: +1, for being the first to make the suggestion.